# I find accessing grb2 files with Pygrib very slow and time consuming, is it same for all?

Tags: python, netcdf

I am using same python code for two data-sets, 
1) i tried to access data from netcdf files 
2) i tried to access data from grb2 files using pygrib. 
Apart from that the code is same(number of steps, loops,total operations - all same). It seems pygrib is hell slow. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't provide a lot of information, but fundamentally GRIB is built differently than NetCDF. GRIB files are normally composed of 1 or more GRIB messages - each GRIB message is a layer and is independent of all other layers. This means you can take a GRIB and concatenate it onto the end of another GRIB, and at the end you will have a GRIB file that contains all messages from both original files. This would not work with NetCDF. So if your data is composed of a lot of different layers (or messages in GRIB terminology) you'll be seeking a lot through your file, even if you're not reading the data payload.

Alternative software are e.g. the [GRIB API releases](https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/GRIB/Releases) from ECMWF. It's fast and reliable, but the Python API is (for the moment at least) very C-like. A new Python API is forthcoming. But without providing more information this question is so general it's hard to answer.

Comment: Dear lee, thanks for immediate response, ill post more information,as of now  this is a satisfactory asnnswer, I will check GRIB API releases , thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this fairly efficiently using [xarray](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/examples/ERA5-GRIB-example.html) with the [cfgrib](https://pypi.org/project/cfgrib/) engine.

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("era5-2mt-2019-03-uk.grib", engine="cfgrib")
```

It reads all messages much more quickly than iterating them with pygrib.